# Using flask based on different python folder

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I have developed a Python game and now I want to incorporate it into a website using Flask for interactivity. Currently, I have two folders: one for my Python code (let's call it Folder X) and another for the Flask project (let's call it Folder Y).

My goal is to display the Python game on the website using Flask while ensuring it remains interactive. However, I'm facing difficulty in retrieving the data from the game folder.

Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='Blockchain_Breakdown_Game')


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():  # put application's code here
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', name='PyCharm')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I have created the following code, and I have a template folder with the same name as my Python game. However, I am uncertain if this is the correct approach to extract the data.

My index.html is basic (html:5), with me indicating index {{ name }}.

Could you please review my code and provide guidance on the correct way to extract the data?

Comment: What exactly is the "data" you want to extract?

Comment: The script is too long to provide, but it is a game simulating blockchain - Not sure if that's what you´re asking

Comment: And how is that game represented? Is it a html page, is it a Python console app, is it a Python GUI app, something else entirely?

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure actually. The game is made using ipywidgets and IPython.display. 
I am not sure if this helps you  - Apologies for my rookieness!

Comment: It kinda does, but that sadly means that what you're trying to do is gonna be quite hard. Flask is a web framework - it runs the Python code server-side and responds over HTTP. It doesn't let you run Python code client side, including IPython.

Comment: Hmm.. Any workarounds?

Comment: Write the entire interface in Flask from scratch? It's really hard to say without knowing what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, I will try to rewrite it then - High likely, I'll be back with more questions ;)

Much appreciated - thanks!